# Bad shim signature

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu, debian

I tried to install Debian 12.4.0 on the second drive, Kubuntu 23.10 is already installed on the first drive.  I checked  I checked  [compatibility](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=4a2deac69b) using the live version, the installations run fine. Unfortunately I can't get Debian to boot

```
 error: bad shim signature
 error: you need to load the kernel first
```

Is there any solution to this problem?

The Debian installer does not create a Grub menu item installed by Kubuntu on the first disk, it is necessary to use the update-grub command in Kubuntu.

Comment: Those look like two questions in one ... The Debian installation one is off-topic but FWIW  the `error: bad shim signature` is most likely a BIOS secure boot issue ... The Kubuntu question is not clear yet either.

Comment: Ubuntu includes *patches* so other OSes are searched for and added to grub for multi-boot environments (*all releases*), Debian however does not, using the upstream code that will detect other OSes with older versions of grub, but not searching outside of known Debian partition(s) for recent releases.  Refer https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2021-December/041769.html for clues; but this was patched in Ubuntu & needs manual user-fix in Debian; and Debian is a non-Ubuntu system & thus off-topic here.  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

For secure boot, the BIOS has a set of embedded certificate that are used to check every item in the boot process. In case an item isn't signed by a certificate, it's not loaded, and the boot process stalls at that point.

The root certificate for all of secure boot, as of now, is `Microsoft's Microsoft UEFI CA 2011` (to expire in 2026, and then replaced `Microsoft UEFI CA 2023`), which is present in all BIOS which have secure boot enabled on purchase.

For secure boot, Linux has a first stage boot loader called the `shim`. The code for the shim is shared across all the flavors of Linux, but each Linux distribution creates a shim binary with their own signing key's Certificate embedded into it, and gets this signed with by Microsoft (with `Microsoft UEFI CA 2011`), which allows the signed instances of `shim` to be boot via the secure boot process.

These signed `shim` binaries cannot be shared across distributions due to the embedded certificate. The shim binary for Kubuntu (i.e. shim with Ubuntu's certificate embedded in it) cannot recognize the Debian signed kernel as valid, and vice versa.

To be able to dual-boot, you will need to have the shim, grub and kernel chains of both available separately. This also means that you cannot have a common shared grub config.